# Abelian covers of smooth algebraic varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, smooth-functions, abelian-varieties

For each smooth algebraic variety $X$ over some field $F$, does there exist an abelian variety $Y$ defined over $F$ (or some extension of $F$) with an unramified (or étale) morphism $Y \rightarrow X$?

If not, under what conditions does an abelian cover exist? If such a cover by an *algebraic* variety $Y$ is given, is there some way to check whether it is *abelian*?

Comment: This appears to be a highly restrictive condition. Say $F$ is the complex numbers. The existence of such a morphism would imply that $\pi_1(Y)$ injects into $\pi_1(X)$. So if $X$ is such that $\pi_1(X)$ does not contain a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbf Z^{2d}$ where $d$ is the dimension of $X$, then no such morphism exists.

Comment: If you had such an etale finite cover, that would imply that $K_X$ is torsion in the Picard group, a very restrictive condition.